# Modal form is empty with PushModalAsync with Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a form that includes a Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map control. When I push new views onto the stack with `await Navigation.PushAsync(page)`, views that I want to be modal (using `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page)`) that I push onto the stack are empty.  The animation works fine, but what's animated is just empty (the background is white but with no controls or other UI elements rendered. If I remove the map control from the "root" view, the modal pages are displayed correctly. If I use .PushAsync instead of .PushModalAsync the views are displayed correctly.

I am targeting Android 6 using the Google emulators

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

it looks like we have a bug on the Xamarin Forms ModalNavigation. It was already reported here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43692
For now, I'm using this workaround (from Scott Simms): before pushing a any page (in the OnDisappearing()) from a page that contains a MapView, remove the MapView from the Content of current page, and load it again in the OnAppearing();
It works well for next page BUT... if you push a new wrapped ModalPage on this second page, when you pop it, probably it will crash your app too.
It has been bothering me, and I am thinking about implement my own toolbar to make it looks like a Navigation Page and avoid the annoying crashing.